# RabbitMQ listener can't convert message

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have message producer which sends message on rabbit using RabbitTemplate. It has message converter:  Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.

I am trying to receive the message from the listener like that:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "kolejka")
public void listen(String message) {
    try {
        log.info("Received ---------------------------------------------------");
        log.info(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Error thrown while listening + " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, message is array of numbers from 45 to 130, it is like Ascii, so my listener has bad encoding. 
I tried changing listener method to listen(Message message) and then 
convert message to object like:

```
public void listen(Message messsage) {
    Transfer transfer = (Transfer) jackson2JsonMessageConverter.fromMessage(messsage);
```

but it throws me warning that message wasn't encoded properly and was thrown on dead letter queue.